# Swagger 1.2 endpoint configuration is not loading

Tags: configuration, swagger

Im new Swagger user. I created endpoint with long model definition.
But when endpoint is attached to  api-docs, this is not working. I checked that that  endpoint configuration file is valid JSON file.

**How to check where is the problem with with this file?**

Im using Swagger 1.2.

Comment: You need to provide more information - which development language/framework do you use? Which Swagger implementation?

Comment: Im using Swagger 1.2:), for doing api documentation for python RESTful Web API.... what else I can say:)? Oythin frameworks is importnat to answer my question?

Comment: Each framework and language has its own way to integrate Swagger into it. Swagger 1.2 is the spec version, not the library. If you don't provide the relevant information, nobody would be able to assist you to solve the problem.

Comment: We are using python with flask.

Comment: I dont havebproblem with API, but api definition file in swagger . Maybe I wrongly describe this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using bin/validate.sh should be able to help validate the files

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#validating-your-swagger-spec

e.g.

```
./bin/validate.sh http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api/api-docs "specia-key" ./swagger-errors.html
```